# No me carga Highcharts en mi Template en Django

Tags: django, highcharts, charts

Tengo creado un Template para probar los charts que necesito para mi proyecto y copiando y pegando el mismo codigo de ejempo de la pagina oficial de Highcharts el template para luego adaptarlos a mi sitio y no me muestra la gráfica y no se que tengo mal.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>{% extends 'body.html' %} {% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="graf_col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block extraresources %}
<script type="applicaton/javascript">
                        Highcharts.chart('graf_col',{
                                chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                                },
                                title: {
                                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                categories: [
                                    'Jan',
                                    'Feb',
                                    'Mar',
                                    'Apr',
                                    'May',
                                    'Jun',
                                    'Jul',
                                    'Aug',
                                    'Sep',
                                    'Oct',
                                    'Nov',
                                    'Dec'
                                ],
                                crosshair: true
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                                }
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                                footerFormat: '</table>',
                                shared: true,
                                useHTML: true
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                name: 'New York',
                                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                                }]
                            });
                </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Por favor alguna idea para la solución? Tengo importado los highcharts.js en el head.html y tampoco funciona. No tengo idea donde puede estar el fallo. Estoy trabajando con Django 3.2.1.